# Javascript import class from file yields "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier"

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, import

I am refactoring my javascript code to make it more object-oriented, but I cannot get the newest features applying classes to work!

First, I declare the class in a separate file as follows:

```
// models/player.js 
export default class Player {

   constructor() {
      //loads of code
   }
}
```

Then, I refer to the file in my html as follows:

```
<script src="js/models/player.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="js/game.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Finally, I try to import the class into my main js file as such:

```
// game.js
import Player from './models/player';
```

But for some reason, Chrome (even Canary) throws me the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier" in that very first import line!

I'm trying to follow all the specifications and examples I can find online. What am I missing?

Comment: You can only use `import` in a script with `type=module`.

Comment: Ahhhh.... I thought it was the other way around!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

import and exports are only good to use in module system like using webpack, etc. But when you directly insert the script file you don't need it:

```
// models/player.js 
class Player {

   constructor() {
      //loads of code
   }
}

<script src="js/models/player.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/game.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now, you can directly use that class: (in game.js)

```
new Player
```

If you prefer using import export even while inserting script then you must specify its type to be module:

```
<script src="js/models/player.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="js/game.js" type="module"></script>
```

Comment: Ahhh...! I thought I needed to use "import" with classes, but if you put it like that, I'd rather be without! Thanks! This looks like the answer I'm looking for!