# I want to make make index.js as my Entry point

Tags: javascript, module

To make my code more readable I would like to split all my functions into different files. I have tried:

```
import {myExport} from '/function.js'
```

but unfortunately, this isn't working. Any ideas on how to make the *index.js* as a single entry point?

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53211185/javascript-import-class-from-file-yields-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-ident/53211338#53211338